# Detect if date is numeric date (and not from relative format)

Tags: php, date

I have some various field from user inpout and from the system. The context is I don't know for all variables if the variable is a date, neither the expected date format from the system.
If the user respond to a field 'when do you need it' by 'now', I don't want the value to be treated as the current date.

Do you have a simple way to detect if the date is a valid date like http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php

but **not**  a valid string for strtotime?

The test set expected is: `[$input, $expected]`:

```
[new \DateTime(), true],
[new \DateTimeImmutable(), true],
['2000-01-01', true],
['31/12/2000', true],
['01-01-1995', true],
['@1306123200', true],
['2010-04-25 02:24:16+12:00', true],

['12/31/2000', false],
['31/31/2000', false],
['now', false],
['next week', false],
[new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris'), false],
[false, false],
[0, false],
[true, false],
[1, false],
['1', false],
['1.1', false],
["", false],
[null, false],
[[], false],
[new \stdClass(), false],
["hi", false],
```

So far I'm checking by checking words:

```
foreach (['day', 'month', 'year', 'next', 'last', 'previous', 'this', 'ago', 'week', 'sun', 'mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat', 'now'] as $needle) {
        $res = strpos($value, $needle);
        if ($res !== false) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Then trying to create a date object

```
try {
    new \DateTime((string) $value);
    return true;
} catch (\Exception $e) {
```

Full function:

```
public function isDate($value)
{
    if ($value instanceof \DateTimeInterface) {
        return true;
    }

    if ($value === false || $value === null || $value === '') {
        return false;
    }

    if (is_numeric($value)) {
        return false;
    }

    //protection for strtotime valid strings
    if (is_string($value)) {
        //1999-19-19 should pass
        if (strpos($value, '-') && !preg_match('/[0-9]-[0-9]/', $value)) {
            return false;
        }
        //2010-04-25 02:24:16+12:00 should pass
        if (strpos($value, '+') && !preg_match('/[0-9]+[0-9]/', $value)) {
            return false;
        }

        foreach (['day', 'month', 'year', 'next', 'last', 'previous', 'this', 'ago', 'week', 'sun', 'mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat', 'now'] as $needle) {
            $res = strpos($value, $needle);
            if ($res !== false) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    try {
        new \DateTime((string) $value);
        return true;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {

    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Out of interest, why do you care? If something's parseable as a date/time, then you can understand what it means. So why would that be a problem? Anyway as per http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php it accepts exactly the same date formats you're linking to in the question. So a valid string as per that link is also a valid string for the strtotime method. They're one and the same. It's not really clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: @ADyson I care because I have to deal with various system/user serialized to string to do some extra treatment if it is a date. If a user write 'next friday' in some field i don't want it to be translatable to a date. Could seems stupid

Comment: " If a user write 'next friday' in some field i don't want it to be translatable to a date". Why not? The intent is clear enough. However if you really want to do it, then one way people do date validation is to decide they only accept dates in a single format (e.g. yyyy-mm-dd or dd/mm/yyyy or whatever) and then use a regular expression to initially check for the _format_ and then afterwards try to parse the date to see if it's a real date (not something like 31/02/2018 for instance). It also helps with anything potentially ambiguous like dd/mm/yyyy vs mm/dd/yyyy etc.

Comment: @ADyson If the user respond to a field `when do you need it?` by `now`, I don't want the value to be treated as the current date.

Comment: It won't, it'll be translated into the date/time represented by now at that moment and then that static value is stored. That statement is of course assuming you're not storing the literal input from the user as a string in your database, and are using proper datetime fields, and are actually parsing the input into a PHP DateTime object (or at least a timestamp which is then convertible to a date), rather than just checking whether it _could_ be parsed...

Comment: @ADyson What are you talking about? There is no problematic of storing or validating anything in my question. I'm sorry and I thank you for your help but my problem seems very clear (to me ;D), I added a dataset to helps understand the needs. Is the `how I came to that need` that important?

Comment: You said " If the user respond to a field when do you need it? by now, I don't want the value to be treated as the current date". And I explained that if you are storing your data properly, then this situation cannot arise. I was concerned that since you were worried about this, it might be that you are not storing dates correctly in your system, that's all. I can't tell either way from the code posted, so it seemed reasonable to ask. There's no need to get cross.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164252/discussion-between-goto-and-adyson).